# Error with GetItemQueryIterator when using a custom CosmosSerializer

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to make use of System.Text.Json serialization for a project I'm working on.  When I make use of a custom CosmosSerializer and call GetItemQueryIterator, the ToStream call is being sent a Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.SqlQuerySpec that cannot be serialized.  Here is a sample that should easily reproduce the problem.   Any and all help is appreciated!

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CosmosTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        const string endpoint = "<REPLACE>";
        const string key = "<REPLACE>";
        const string dbName = "test";
        const string containerName = "items";

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new CosmosClientOptions()
            {
                Serializer = new CosmosJsonSerializer()
            };
            var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, key, options);

            var dbResponse = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(dbName);
            var db = dbResponse.Database;
            var containerDef = new ContainerProperties(containerName, "/id");
            var containerResposne = await db.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerDef);
            var testContainer = containerResposne.Container;

            var testDoc = new TestDoc();
            var docResponse = await testContainer.CreateItemAsync(testDoc, new PartitionKey(testDoc.Id));
            Console.WriteLine($"Created document {docResponse.Resource.Id}");

            var query = testContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<TestDoc>("SELECT * FROM c");
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var doc = await query.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach(var x in doc.Resource)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved document {x.Id}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal class CosmosJsonSerializer : CosmosSerializer
    {
        public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                stream.Close();
                var item = JsonSerializer.Parse<T>(memoryStream.ToArray());
                return item;
            }
        }

        //This errors on the SqlQuerySpec 
        public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
            => new MemoryStream(JsonSerializer.ToUtf8Bytes(input));

    }

    internal class TestDoc
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; } = "1";

        public string TestString { get; set; } = "testing CosmosJsonSerializer";
    }

}
```

EDIT:  Bug has been filed and confirmed here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/575